# The best way to store big number of files with adding quick search

Tags: sqlite, isolatedstorage, sqlite-net

In my Windows 8/RT app I use SQLite DataBase ([sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net)) witch store in Isolated Storage. In DataBase I have a lot of data, including files(images, pdf's and other) links. I get those links from web server. When I got link, I want to download file and store it locally. 
My question is: what is the best way to store big number of files (100+)?
 One important think: **I need to organize quickly find the desired file**.

I have three ideas:

1. Create another DataBase only for files (I can't modify existing)
2. Create folder in IS and store here directly.
3. Create list of files and store it in IS.

Which would be better/faster? Or somebody have another great solution?

Comment: what are average and largest file sizes you expect?

Comment: max size == 5Mb, average size == 1Mb

Answer (score 0):

100 files isn't such a big number as you can easily store up to 100k files (or folders) in a single (NTFS) directory.

If you receive the files from a webserver then the question is whether the source makes sure there are no duplicate filenames. If this can't be assured, I'd recommend having a database table mapping from original filename and metadata to its hash (SHA256 or similar) and store the file with a filename corresponding to its hash.

Then, when using the file, you can pass pass it to the user using the original filename using the StorageFile API.

Going beyond 100k files, you could create a subfolder structure from the first two letters of the hash.

Either way, storing the file metadata in a database and the files in a directory has been the most useful approach for us in the past.

Answer (score 0):

100 files with average size of 1MB is only 100MB.

Most people say that storing binary files in database is wrong and suggest storing files separately and only keep file names in database, but I think it is fine provided you know what you are doing and why.

Big advantage of storing files in database is that you keep files together with their properties logically in one place. Also, you can simply copy one file and this would backup everything.

Database also affords you transaction support. You may have some problems reading and writing BLOBs into database, but it is not very difficult.

Comment: Why do people say that? Storing files separately is brittle if you always access them via the database.

Comment: I don't know why. I tend to use database for everything. I would probably reconsider if my files were more than 100MB

Comment: I think it is often just an automatic association: documents are usually files on a filesystem so it doesn't occur to the developer that they can also be stored in a different way.